# Why is my output file different from my input file?

Tags: c++

I am reading from a text file and writing to a text file but the Output file does not match the input file.

The original TINN1 file was written by a Fortran program as a text file. Using mixed programming Fortan/C++ I was able to initialize my array in Fortran and pass it over to C++ to write an output file that was a mirror of the input file. However doing a read and write in C++ is proving a challenge. I was able to produce the code using other examples found using google.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<sstream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<iomanip>
    #include<cstdlib>

    main()
    {

    double ta1[22];
    double tv1[22];
    double t1[22][13][22];
    ifstream in;    // Create an input file stream.
    ofstream out;    // Create an input file stream.
    int ik;

    in.open("TINN1");  // Use it to read from a file named data.txt.
    out.open("TINN1.txt");  // Use it to read from a file named data.txt.

    for (int k=1; k<=21; k++){
      in >> ik , ta1[k] , tv1[k];
      out << ik << " " << ta1[k] << " " << tv1[k] << endl;
      for (int i=1; i<=21; i++){
        if (i<=15) {
          for (int j=1; j<=12; j++) {
            in >> t1[k][j][i];
            out << t1[k][j][i] << " " ;
            if (j % 6 == 0) out << endl;
          }
        }
        else{
          //         for (int =; <=; ++){do 2 j=1,12
          //         t(i,j,k)=32.0
          //   2     continue
        }
      }
    }

    return 0;
    }


    input file has the following:
    1 36.20  0.00
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62
    36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62
    36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55
    36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55
    36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14
    36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14
    33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64
    33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64
    32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46
    32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46
    32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26
    32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26
    32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06
    32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06
    31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97
    31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97
    31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86
    31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86

    Output file has the following:
    1 nan 4.89317e+018
    36.2 0 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63 36.63
    36.63 36.63 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62
    36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62 36.62
    36.62 36.62 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55
    36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55 36.55
    36.55 36.55 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 
    36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 36.14 
    36.14 36.14 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 
    33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 33.64 
    33.64 33.64 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 
    32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 32.46 
    32.46 32.46 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 
    32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 32.26 
    32.26 32.26 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 
    32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 32.06 
    32.06 32.06 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 
    31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 31.97 
    31.97 31.97 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 
    31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 31.86 

    The two files should be the same
```

Comment: This code urgently needs proper indentation so we can better follow the structure and your intent.

Comment: Updated code per your recommendation thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
in >> ik , ta1[k] , tv1[k];
```

should be:

```
in >> ik >> ta1[k] >> tv1[k];
```

Comment: That is scary the compiler didn't warn me that there was an error. I am a native fortran programmer and so used the "," rather than ">>" thanks for pointing it out to me. :)

Comment: The comma operator is valid syntax here, but in this context it basically says: Just read into ik, and don't worry about ta1[k] or tv1[k]. (Which is clearly not your intent!)